# Unable to register EnumCodec via Spring Boot R2DBC auto-config

Tags: spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc-postgresql

I'm using

1. `spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc 3.1.4`
2. `r2dbc-postgresql 1.0.2.RELEASE`

I've

1. created `TYPE MY_ENUM AS ENUM`
2. created `MyEnumConverter extends org.springframework.data.r2dbc.convert.EnumWriteSupport<MyEnum>` as a `@WritingConverter` and registerd it with `org.springframework.data.r2dbc.convert.R2dbcCustomConversions`
3. Explicitly mapped `private MyEnum myEnum` into the 'entity mapping'
4. persisted a freshly created entity via `org.springframework.data.repository.reactive.ReactiveCrudRepository#save`

And got the following error

```
reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot encode parameter of type MyEnum
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot encode parameter of type MyEnum
    at io.r2dbc.postgresql.codec.DefaultCodecs.encodeParameterValue(DefaultCodecs.java:290) ~[r2dbc-postgresql-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]
    at io.r2dbc.postgresql.codec.DefaultCodecs.encode(DefaultCodecs.java:264) ~[r2dbc-postgresql-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]
    at io.r2dbc.postgresql.PostgresqlStatement.bind(PostgresqlStatement.java:108) ~[r2dbc-postgresql-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]
    at io.r2dbc.postgresql.PostgresqlStatement.bind(PostgresqlStatement.java:59) ~[r2dbc-postgresql-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]
    ...
```

---

The configuration to R2DBC was done entirely by Spring Boot Auto Config and I do not want to move away from that. Specifically `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.r2dbc.ConnectionFactoryConfigurations.PoolConfiguration.PooledConnectionFactoryConfiguration#connectionFactory`

I want to keep the auto-config, but it does not expose any entry to register an `EnumCodec` instance, as far as my whole-day-research goes, I debugged the `io.r2dbc.postgresql.PostgresqlStatement` at runtime and it was indeed using default `Codecs`.

Could I please get any help, thank you in advance.